# Dropdown menu disappearing

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm fairly new to web design and I've been working on a CSS way of creating a drop down menu which appears initially when a parent div is hovered. However once visible, I need the menu to stay up until the mouse is moved off the whole menu.

I've been able to make the menu appear and disappear, however it disappears too quickly - disappearing when I leave the parent div. Example below.

I've tried nesting within a third div which changes between display:block and display:none but no luck

Code

```
<div class="menuc">
<div class="menua"></div>
<div class="menub">
<p class="footertext">Home</p>
<p class="footertext">Home</p>
<p class="footertext">Home</p>
<p class="footertext">Home</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.menua {
width:200px;
height:50px;
background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
z-index:999;
}


.menua:hover ~ div.menub {
opacity:1;
z-index:999;
}

.menub {
width:200px;
height:600px;
background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
opacity:0;
-webkit-transition: opacity .5s linear;
-moz-transition: opacity .5s linear;
-ms-transitiom: opacity .5s linear; 
-o-transition: opacity .5s linear; 
transition: opacity .5s linear;
z-index:999;
display:block;
}

.menuc {
display:none;
}

.menuc:hover {
display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qp3wu/

Apologies if this is a fairly amateur mistake (doh).

All answers and suggestions greatly appreciated

Comment: *"however it disappears too quickly"* so do you need to hide the menu with a deley on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just let `.menub` element stay when `.menub` itself is **also** hovered:

```
.menua:hover ~ .menub, .menub:hover {
    opacity:1;
}
```

The comma is used the define a new selector. The above is the same as:

```
 .menua:hover ~ .menub{
    opacity:1;
  }

.menub:hover {
    opacity:1;
}
```

But shorter.

**Ignore any event; hide the element, but still use opacity effect**

Now to make sure the `.menub` does not react to any events(like hovering), you can just hide it:

```
.menua:hover ~ .menub, .menub:hover {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity:1;
}
```

and on hover show it again:

```
.menub {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

I use css `visibility` to keep the same effect as you would have with only `opacity`. It will still have the space of the element(unlike what `display: none;` does; collapsing the space).

**Delete remaining space when not visible**

To go even further and fix the remaining spacing, you can add `height: 0;` as default and when hovered set the height to your desired height(`600px` in this case).

---

**Remove the gab inbetween menua and menub**

If you want to get rid of the gab between menua and menub but *still use the default margin*, you can reset the top margin of the first `<p>` element:

```
.menub p:first-child
{
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qp3wu/26/)

*The text beneath the menu's is to show you that there will be no space when the element is not visible.*

Comment: problem with this is you can activate the menu just by hovering over it instead of the parent

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a few changes:

- One wrap the `menub` with `menua` div to keep the hover effect:

  ```
  <div class="menua">
   <div class="menub">
    <p class="footertext">Home</p>
    <p class="footertext">Home</p>
    <p class="footertext">Home</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  ```
- Two position your `menub` inside `menua` i use absolute position. With this you avoid other elements to be moved by the submenu.

  ```
  .menua {
   position:relative;
  }
  .menub {
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
  }
  ```
- Three you can use `opacity` to give an effect but to hide and show you really need `display` property:

  ```
   .menub {
     display:none;
   }
   .menua:hover div.menub {
     display:block;
   }
  ```

An example **http://jsfiddle.net/qp3wu/23/**